# Remove full stop in string

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a file `test.txt`, get all words one by one, and then removing dots and commas from read words.

Here is my code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Utils {
    public static void readFile(){
        Scanner word = null;
        try {
            word = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (word.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(word.nextLine());
            Utils.cleanWord(s2);
            while (s2.hasNext()) {
                String s = s2.next();

                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void cleanWord(String word){
        word = word.replace(".", "");
    }
```

When I compile my code, I get this error `Error:(18, 29) java: incompatible types: java.util.Scanner cannot be converted to java.lang.String`

Does anyone know which type should I give to `cleanWord` method please, so that it can perform remove operation on words. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `Utils.cleanWord(s2)` where `s2` is a `Scanner` and not a `String`.

Your code should be:

```
while(s2.hasNext()) { 
    String s = s2.next(); //or s2.nextLine(); depending on what you want..
    s = Utils.cleanWord(s);
    System.out.println(s); 
}
```

Also, Java parameters are references, not pointers. You cannot assign to word parameter and expect it to change outside the function..

```
private static void cleanWord(String word){
    word = word.replace(".", "");
}
```

should actually be:

```
private static String cleanWord(String word){
    return word.replace(".", "");
}
```

because you can't modify the parameter.. Trying to will result in modifying the local reference of the parameter and not the parameter itself.